# How to filter AD Object attributes for VMware Horizon?

Tags: powershell, ldap, vmware

We are using **VMware Horizon** and I'm trying to filter out some attributes about the computers but I cant figure how to do it.

I've done a lot of google searches and these codes should be working but they don't.

```
Get-ADObject -server "localhost:389" -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=vdi,DC=vmware,DC=int" -Filter *
```

*ERROR: Get-ADObject : Directory object not found*

```
$path = 'LDAP://localhost:389/dc=vdi,dc=vmware,dc=int'

Try{
$root = [adsi]::new($path)
$searcher = [adsisearcher]$root
$searcher.findone() }
Catch{
Write-Host "ERROR: $_"}
```

*ERROR: Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The specified directory service attribute or value does not 
exist.*

I have access to the server and I can see the objects in ADSI Edit, but somehow I still can't query out a single item from the ad.

I appreciate every help since it took away a lot more time from me than it should have done..

Best regards

Comment: Did you verify that the LDAP is available on localhost? Do you query the same LDAP with ADSI Edit?

Comment: `-Filter ` what?

Comment: Yes I use the same LDAP in my script and in the ADSI edit.

@Theo I edited the code here, first of all I'm trying to get all the objects in the Servers OU, as soon as I'll be able to get at least 1 item my problem is solved.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error indicates the `-SearchBase` is incorrect. Is there a typo? Is there case-sensitivity in this console and are you matching case perfectly in your search base?

Comment: I believe that the Searchbase should be the distinguishedName of the folder where we store the servers.

I copied the DistinguishedName so typos and case-sensivity issues should not happen